# Darwin not supported yet for MKL build / configure for Tensorflow

Tags: ios, macos, tensorflow, darwin

I am trying to Use tensorflow-1.3.0 in my iOS App. I am Trying this link -[http://jeffxtang.github.io/deep/learning,/tensorflow,/mobile,/ai/2016/09/23/mobile-tensorflow.html][1]

I am trying Step 4 from this tutorial, I need to run ./configure script before I can run bazel build to run the retrain script:

```
bazel build tensorflow/examples/image_retraining:retrain
bazel-bin/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain \
  --model_dir=/tf_files/inception-v3 \
  --output_graph=/tf_files/retrained_models/dog_retrained.pb \
  --output_labels=/tf_files/retrained_models/dog_retrained_labels.txt \
  --image_dir ~/Downloads/dog_images \
  --bottleneck_dir=/tf_files/dogs_bottleneck
```

But the ./configure step fails with the following message:

```
MobioApps-Mac-mini:tensorflow-1.3.0 mobioapp$ ./configure
You have bazel 0.5.3-homebrew installed.
Please specify the location of python. [Default is /Users/mobioapp/anaconda/bin/python]: /Users/mobioapp/anaconda/bin/python
Found possible Python library paths:
  /Users/mobioapp/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Please input the desired Python library path to use.  Default is [/Users/mobioapp/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages]
/Users/mobioapp/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Do you wish to build TensorFlow with MKL support? [y/N] y
MKL support will be enabled for TensorFlow
Do you wish to download MKL LIB from the web? [Y/n] Y
Darwin is unsupported yet
```

Problem : Darwin is unsupported yet

What is the solution for this issue? Please help me out. I am searching a long time for it.

Comment: It's being worked on! https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/10685

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To overcome this problem please skip step number 4 from this link http://jeffxtang.github.io/deep/learning,/tensorflow,/mobile,/ai/2016/09/23/mobile-tensorflow.html .I just followed step 1,2,3 and 5  respectively from the tutorial.This solved my problem and finally i am able to run my own trained model into my iOS App and got successful prediction result.